# IS Relation in Java

Tags: java, entity-relationship, modeling

I want to write a pizza shop where you can order pizza and pasta. This graph shows how I'm thinking of modeling it, but I don't know how to implement the IS relation between dish and pizza/pasta. Any tips on that or anything at all?

[image: entity-relationship-modell]

Comment: Looks very good, I would add an ID for each Dish as well , if for a example a customer wants to report on a specific dish he ate.

Comment: So `Dish` would be an abstract class?

Comment: @Kayaman I was thinking that Pizza and Pasta should extend Dish, but I don't know if that's the right idea

Comment: Well, that's what it looks like in your diagram. From an OO perspective that's correct, but from a business perspective you would of course not hardcode your dishes in code, but store the data in a database and deal with generic dish objects with attributes distinguishing them.

Comment: Small note on terminology: the conventional names for relations in Java are "has-a" and "is-a", not "has" and "is", and you don't model it in a Java UML diagram using a node, instead of you use the appropriate edge type (for "is-a" that's an arrow from the subclass to the superclass, with an optional "is-a" as edge label, but that's usually unnecessary)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the information. This is just how I learned it in my Database class hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dish` will be an abstract class as [Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman) said:

```java
public abstract class Dish {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Double price;
    
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Note that I added the `id` property because I agree with [Vled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17625629/vled):

> Looks very good, I would add an ID for each Dish as well , if for a example a customer wants to report on a specific dish he ate.

So, `Pizza` and `Pasta` will extend it:

##### Pizza

```java
public class Pizza extends Dish {
    private Topping toppings;
    private Sauce sauce;
    private Size size;

    public enum Topping {
        // Topping options
    }

    public enum Sauce {
        // Sauce options
    }

    public enum Size {
        // Size options
    }
}
```

##### Pasta

```java
public class Pasta extends Dish {
    private Topping toppings;
    private Sauce sauce;
    private Type type;

    public enum Topping {
        // Topping options
    }

    public enum Sauce {
        // Sauce options
    }

    public enum Type {
        // Type options
    }
}
```

I put the properties as enums because they will be **options** that will compose the `Dish`.